# iOS- How can I get UIAlertView width with customize and put the UILabel to center

Tags: ios, center, uialertview

I was custom the `UIAlertView`, I need add some component to the `alertView` (like label, tableview).

But I have a question. I need to know the alertView's width.

I try to add `self.frame.size.width`, but I just got the `0.000000`.

How can I get the alertView's width?

I will calculate to put the subview at, and put the `UILabel` to subview to center. My partial code below:

**.h file:**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface CustomTableViewAlert : UIAlertView

 -(instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...;


 @end
```

**.m file:**

```
   #import "CustomTableViewAlert.h"

  ...
   @implementation CustomTableViewAlert


 -(instancetype) initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
 {
   self = [super initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self      cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles, nil];

if( self )
{

 NSLog(@"=====self.frame.size.width:%f",self.frame.size.width);
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ I got 0.000000

    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;

    float showInAlertWidth = screenSize.width - 100;
    float showInAlertHeight = 150;

    CGSize textSize = [[notFoundDeviceLabel text] sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[notFoundDeviceLabel font]}];

    CGFloat strikeWidth = textSize.width;
    CGFloat strikeHeight = textSize.height;
    [notFoundDeviceLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, showInAlertHeight)];

    notFoundDeviceLabel.text = @"No Device found";
    notFoundDeviceLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    // new container view
    containerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, showInAlertHeight)];
    containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [containerView addSubview: notFoundDeviceLabel];
}

return self;
 }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Read the docs for `UIAlertView`. It is not meant to be subclasses or modified at all. It states: *"The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."*

Comment: Adding to what @rmaddy said, the docs also state: "_Important: UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that UIAlertViewDelegate is also deprecated.) To create and manage alerts in iOS 8 and later, instead use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert._"

Comment: Can UIAlertController add the UITableView ?thanks.

Comment: The same applies to UIAlertController, "_The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified._"

Answer (score 1):

Although subclassing UIAlertView may (and most likely) will result in the rejection of your app by Apple, it's still possible. You will have to override `layoutSubviews` and `drawRect`. I've found fairly good tutorial [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-uialertview-custom-graphics--mobile-8886), which iterates through the process of finding the active bounds and inset of the alert view, which would allow you to find the width.

Just remember:

1. UIAlertView is not meant to be subclassed.
2. As of iOS 8, UIAlertView is deprecated and you should use UIAlertController.

Answer (score 0):

You should not subclass UIAlertView, APPLE has strictly said no from iOS 7 onwards. All you have to do is create a custom UIView, add UITableView as subview and so on based on your requirement.

UIAlertController is new with iOS 8, so adopting it may sound good for iOS 8 only but for iOS 7 it would be problem.

Better do UIView subclassing instead of UIAlertView.

Comment: So I should custom a UIView that like alertview, and custom pop up window in from of the view?@@ I just want to show the pop up window to user select the bluetooth device. Have any good method(except the use navigation page)?

Comment: yes use custom UIView, add a FullView with some transparency so that it will block interactions with viewcontroller unless alertview is dismissed. On top of that add another UIView (add UITableview + Cancel, OK buttons) to it. Handle the button actions, use some delegate to find the cell selected.

Comment: sorry, Can UIAlertController achieve the effect( contain the uitableView)?thanks,@ibiren. Because I think to custom the UIView,we had to control the UIVIew dismiss or not. It was become complex.

Comment: I think you can subclass, but it would only work in iOS 8 devices.