# iOS How to control the UIContainer View show and disappear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uicontainerview

I had a `UIViewController` and a `UIContainer` View.

I want to simulate the `UIAlertView` effect, But I don't know how to build the Container View show and hide about the great method.

I had put the `UITableView` in my `UIContainer` View,  I use delegate to send selected item to the `UIViewController`(`ParentViewController`) and show in the label.( segue name with `alertSegue`)

There have a show button in the `ParentViewController`,and I need click the selected item ,it will close(hide/dismiss?) the `UIContainer` View.

Now `UIContainer` View default is hidden,and storybaord screen shot like below:

[image]

My **ParentViewController.h**

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController<ContainerViewBLETableDelegate>

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
 - (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lb;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerView;

 -(IBAction)unwindSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;

 @end
```

**.m file:**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
 }

 - (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender {
     _containerView.hidden = NO;

 }

 -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
     if( [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"alertSegue"])
     {
         ContainerViewBLETable *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
         vc.delegate = self;
     }
 }

 -(void) ContainerViewBLETable:(ContainerViewBLETable *)vc      andSelectedDone:(NSString *)selectedStr
 {
     self.lb.text = selectedStr;
     vc.view.hidden = YES;
 }

 -(IBAction)unwindSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
 {
 }
```

Container ViewController .h :

```
 @class ContainerViewBLETable;
 @protocol ContainerViewBLETableDelegate <NSObject>

 -(void) ContainerViewBLETable:(ContainerViewBLETable*)vc andSelectedDone:(NSString*)selectedStr;

 @end

 @interface ContainerViewBLETable :      UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

 @property(nonatomic,assign) id<ContainerViewBLETableDelegate>delegate;

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableVW;

 @end
```

UIContainerView .m part:

```
 .....
 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    [self.delegate ContainerViewBLETable:self andSelectedDone:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",indexPath.row]];
 }
 .....
```

Although  this code  can pass the value to the `UIViewController`(`ParentViewController`),and the `UIContainer` View was hidden,but when I click the show button again , it was not any effect(I feel the container view was overlap lead to touch  lose efficacy).

( by the way, I had try

```
 [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

it's not effect )

**Question:**

How to hide the container view use the delegate and that can touch the show button show container again?

And What great method to control the `UIContainer` view show and disappear in `ParentViewController` and `UIContainerView` ?

I really thank everyone and you can help me and better than better.

Comment: So when you select the cell in `containerView` in `ContainerViewBLETable`, it will push to `ParentViewController ` which has a label showing `show`?

Comment: when I select the cell in the containerView, I will hide the ContainerView , and it will pass the value to the ParentViewController using delegate.the label showing in the parentviewcontroller. Then when I click the "show button" ,I need show the container view again.

Answer (score 0):

`containerView` and `show button` are in different viewControllers. So you can't just hide it. The simple way to achieve it is when you select the cell in `containerView`, present the `ParentViewController`, and the view in `ContainerViewController` will dismiss automatically.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [self.delegate ContainerViewBLETable:self andSelectedDone:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",indexPath.row]];
   ParentViewController *vc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ParentViewController"];
   [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

To show the container, you can just dismiss the `ParentViewController` that presenting.
1.

```
- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender 
{
   [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Or
   2. Set up segue to dismiss viewController and use prepareForSegue for delegate to communicate with other viewController.

Also **REMOVE** `vc.view.hidden = YES` in delegate you had implemented

```
 -(void) ContainerViewBLETable:(ContainerViewBLETable *)vc andSelectedDone:(NSString *)selectedStr.
```

Comment: I was cancel the container view hidden. But at initial, the container view was show, so I add the [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
in viewdidload, it still same situation. the parenetview always showing include the container view. If you can, I had post the project in github. you can check the effect . :(  https://github.com/dickfalaDeveloper/popalertShow   thank you very mch.

Comment: yes, When click the button show the container view, click the container table cell  hide container view . it is my purpose. thanks.

Comment: You had embed segue to containerViewBE Table, rather the containerViewBE controller. And you need to connect the segue between `show button` and the `containerViewController`. And I misunderstood you sense about the vc hierarchy. The `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method should call `dismiss` rather `present`. Sorry about that, my fault.

Comment: Sorry~ The problem was not resolve. I need simulate UIAlertView effect, so I use container view. Could you try to change my test project code achieve  the effect? I confuse more time:(

Comment: @dickfala What UIAlertView effect you mean？

Comment: I want to build the effect like: http://postimg.org/image/5a1hwckvn/   That can put uitableview in ContainerView with iOS8.  Because iOS8 can't use UIAlertView subclass. So I want to practice use the ContainerView contain some components.

Comment: In general ,you may need to open a new question about how to implement this UIAlertView effect.

Comment: I had try to search some UIAlertView method. I know we can use subclass extends UIAlertView to build this effect in iOS7. But We can't use the method in the iOS8. I had try to ask similar question in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535868/ios-how-can-i-get-uialertview-width-with-customize-and-put-the-uilabel-to-cente. But Still not find good implement answer....Orz So I try to implement the effect use containerView. But I still encounter the problem more time.