# iOS Setting XIB width are exceed the view width in the storyboard

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib

How can I set the xib size with iOS8? I have a view in the Storyborad, and I had set the autoLayout (constraints) like below.

[image]

The view had link to the xib file in the Storyboard. But when I compile the code. The xib width will exceed the view width with my setting( I had set the autoLayout constraints with UILabel).

xib stats:
[image]

In the iPhone, the xib is exceed the view.

[image]
 How can I set the xib size fit the view in the storyboard?

hank you very much.

----- update -----
document outline :
[image]

The project file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ggc82dgvp6fjhmg/reuseableXib.zip?dl=0

Comment: Using auto layout with correct constraints the will fit the screen size, are you sure that the green view is not contained in another view with wrong constraints?

Comment: Yes, There are not any wrong constraints message. I update the photo about the Document Outline.And I upload my project about these layout, can you see where the problems ? thank you @Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not super easy. I do not know why Apple didn't make this out of the box.

However it is possible, try this for example:
http://cocoanuts.mobi/2014/03/26/reusable/

If you want an easy approach, start using container views instead (i.e. put the view in storyboard and make embed segue to it). This will clog up your storyboard for big projects though.

Comment: I use xib reason is I have more different reuse view, that have to dynamic add the same view. But the view default is close, when I click the button, it will pop up cover the window(like the alertview). If I use container view, that can't set close and open(I had post question at here ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823019/ios-how-to-control-the-uicontainer-view-show-and-disappear). That was not resolve, so I change other method to set the xib .